# HttpHandler Path Issue ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, httphandler, path

I've written an HttpHandler that works fine when I test it on the ASP.NET development server.

In my Web.Config I have:

```
<add verb="*" path="Files.zip" type="MyNamespace.Zip, App_Code" />
```

And in my Handler in my App_Code folder I have the code below.  Unfortunately, since the ASP.NET development server dumps everthing in the root -- http://localhost:1234/Files.zip works just fine.  However, I'm trying to deploy to an intranet server where the the URL is something like http://myProjects/project.  When I point my browser to http://myProjects/project/Files.zip I get a 404.  How can I tweak the web config to get the right path?  Or is the solution somewhere else?  I've already tried prefixing the path with "~/" and "./".

```
(Namespace MyNamespace, file Zip.cs)
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(context.Server.MapPath("files"));
    FileInfo[] fileinf = di.GetFiles();
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    foreach(FileInfo fi in fileinf)
    {
        zip.AddFile(fi.FullName, "");
    }
    zip.Save(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
```

Comment: IIS version on your deployment server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the mappings set up in IIS on your intranet server such that the requests to *.zip are processed by the ASP.NET runtime?  If not, the the request to files.zip will never get to your handler.

If you're on IIS 6 this link will help you set up the mapping of the aspnet_isapi.dll to zip extensions.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I've tried all possible paths, so it seems this is probably the issue.  Unfortunately I don't have privileges, so it will be hard to test or modify.

Comment: If you're heart is not set on the path ending in .zip you can just change it to be FilesZip.aspx or something similar.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
path="/project/Files.zip"
```